# How do I get the width of a string as it would be displayed on screen?

Tags: slick

What is the best and easiest way to get the width of a String using Slick2D?

I'm working on the achievement interface menu in my game that displays some images. On each image I need to draw a string such as "Reach Level 5.". Only problem is that I don't know how to get the string width to properly center the string on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Font](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc-util/org/newdawn/slick/Font.html) class is the base class for all the fonts used in Slick2D. It has a method called `getWidth(string)` ([documentation](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc-util/org/newdawn/slick/Font.html#getWidth%28java.lang.String%29)). This function returns an integer the represents the width of the string as it would be drawn. This goes for the main two classes that extend `Font`

If using [TrueTypeFont](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.html) you can use `getWidth(string)`, [documentation](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.html#getWidth%28java.lang.String%29).

If using [UnicodeFont](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/UnicodeFont.html) you can use `getWidth(string)`, [documentation](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/UnicodeFont.html#getWidth%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Quick and detailed answer.

Comment: No problem, remember to up vote if it was useful and accept if it worked for you. And welcome to GDSE!